# Azure Data Factory User Configuration Issue/ Cannot Find Object Error 2402

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

In my Pipeline I have an activity calling a stored procedure. I have 2 SQL Server instances where I'm running this pipeline (`DEV` and `PROD`). I pointed my pipeline and datasets in `DEV` and it works fine but when I point this to my `PROD`, it is causing an error.

The process of my stored procedure is just an `Insert` statement into Table 2 and truncate table 1. I also did make sure all the columns, constraints for my table 1 and 2, same stored procedure etc. are all similar in both regions.

Here are the details of the error I think are important:

> Error Code: 2402
> Failure Type: User Configuration issue
> Details: Execution fail against SQL Server. Please contact SQL Server team if you need further support.
> SQL error number: 1088. Error Message: Cannot find the object "Table 1" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

I've removed the INSERT statement from my stored procedure but it seems it's getting an issue because of the `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement.

The next step I did is I've removed the stored procedure and then moved it into a **COPY DATA activity** where I placed the `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement in the pre-copy script property.

I'm still getting an error:

> Error code: SqlOperationFailed
> Failure Type: User Configuration issue
> Details:
> ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed, 'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException, Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Cannot find the object "Table 1" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Cannot find the object "Table 1" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
> Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,
> SqlErrorNumber = 1088, Class = 16, ErrorCode = -2146232060, State = 7,
> Errors=[{Class=16,Number=1088,State=7,Message=Cannot find the object
> "Table 1" because it does not exist or you do not have
> permissions.,},],'

Next step is that I've checked the User server role I'm using in both SQL Servers

```
Security > Logins > Right Click on User1 > Properties > Server Roles menu
```

The only checked box there is "public" for both DEV and PROD. So I'm not sure what's causing an error in my PROD instance if it's all working fine in DEV.

Here are the links I've read so far about this issue.

[User Configuration](https://User%20Configuration%20-%20Data%20Factory%20is%20giving%20error%20of%20Database%20is%20Pause%20but%20synapse%20DW%20database%20is%20running%20-%20Microsoft%20Q&A)

[Microsoft Forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/120432/data-factory-stored-procedure-error-cannot-find-th)

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297082/azure-data-factory-fails-to-execute-copy-data-task-to-sql-server)

Comment: You should find the tables/procedures in the database-tree in Management studio in test and check the rights against it. The issue you're having probably has to do that you have rights in test to work with tables but not in prod.

Comment: @siggemannen Hi, not sure how. Is this in the Properties of each table or object and in Permissions menu on the left side?

Comment: Because based on here the checkboxes are checked only on DELETE, INSERT, SELECT and UPDATE in Grant Column. Does DELETE also corresponds to TRUNCATE or it should be ALTER checkbox should be checked?

Comment: yeah, you need ALTER to be able to truncate. Do you have rights in production to delete etc?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. This is a rights and permissions issue. Instead of TRUNCATE we decided to do DELETE statement instead.